# NullPointerException Caused by getActionBar()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

Trying to set up the Navigation Drawer of an app right now, and every time I try to run the app on my Android device, I get a NullPointerException. The error is caused by `getActionBar.setDisplayHomeUpAsEnabled(true)` and `getActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)`

Even if I remove these two lines of code, I still get an error.

How do I fix this quickly?

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] navDrawerTitles;
    private DrawerLayout navDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    private Fragment blankFrag = new Fragment();
    private final int POSITION = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navDrawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_array);
        navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, navDrawerTitles));

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        navDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
                navDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                //R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        navDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
        // view
        boolean drawerOpen = navDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }


    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    /**
     * Starts an Activity when item is clicked
     */
    private void selectItem(int position) {

//        }

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(StartingFragment.TEA_TYPE_POS, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
//      setTitle(navDrawerTitles[position]);
        navDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

> 01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904): Process:
>   appathon.bu.com.appathon, PID: 20904 01-31 14:11:11.298:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{appathon.bu.com.appathon/appathon.bu.com.appathon.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-31 14:11:11.298:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 01-31
>   14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 01-31
>   14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 01-31 14:11:11.298:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146) 01-31
>   14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-31
>   14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 01-31 14:11:11.298:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612) 01-31
>   14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-31 14:11:11.298:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(20904): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   appathon.bu.com.appathon.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 01-31
>   14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
>   01-31 14:11:11.298: E/AndroidRuntime(20904):  ... 11 more

Comment: If you post the full stack trace of the error you may get more help from us.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, if `getActionBar()` in an `Activity` is returning `null`, then you do not have a native action bar in your activity.

Second, `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` does not work with the native action bar. It works with the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport. If you are going to use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`, then you have to move your app over to use `appcompat-v7`:

1. Add `appcompat-v7` as a dependency
2. Inherit from `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`
3. Call `getSupportActionBar()` rather than `getActionBar()`
4. Use `Theme.AppCompat` (or something that inherits from it) as your activity's theme

Comment: If I choose not to use appcompat-v7 as a dependency, then how do I get it to work? Also, even if I remove getActionBar() I get the NPE

Comment: @Freddie_V4: "then how do I get it to work?" -- you don't. You would have to use something else, other than `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`. "Also, even if I remove getActionBar() I get the NPE" -- your pasted-in stack trace is barely readable, and I have no way to know what line it is that you are crashing on.

Comment: OK. Well I added the appcompat-v7 dependency, inherited from Activity, called getActionBar and I am using Theme.appcompat. I am still unable to get the app to run properly. What can I post for you so that you can help me further?

Comment: @Freddie_V4: Sorry, I am a moron, and miswrote bullets #2 and #3. My sincere apologies. Try the updated ones (reverse of the originals). If you're still crashing, add an update to your question with your now-current code, the stack trace, and an indication of what line(s) in your code correspond to references to them in the stack trace.

Comment: The problem now is that my R file does not seem to be generating (Android Studio)

Comment: @Freddie_V4: That indicates a problem in one of your resources, or perhaps your manifest. Choose Build > Rebuild Project from the main menu, and see if you get a specific error in the Gradle Console to work from.

Comment: I tried Rebuild and it did work.. For 2 seconds and then I got the same exact error. The error is: content not allowed in prolog

Comment: @Freddie_V4: Whichever XML resource you are referring to has whitespace or something before the `<?xml` bit at the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69969/discussion-between-freddie-v4-and-commonsware).

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? I don't see anything wrong. This is my most updated code http://pastebin.com/KAHWMtUc

Comment: @Freddie_V4: "What exactly are you referring to?" -- I am referring to your previous comment. "This is my most updated code" -- none of that is an XML file. The error message you have gotten comes from a malformed XML file, and the error listing should indicate what file has a problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare what makes getSupportActionBar() ? whats the difference between getSupportActionBar() and getActionBar()?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you. My solution was to set theme with ThemeAppCompat, make your activity extend AppCompatActivity and use the method of getSupportActionBar instead of using the method of getActionBar. In short, you should make sure the actionBar of theme and the method which to get actionBar have the same support library.